# bootstrap content leaving responsive table

Tags: html

I have noticed that bootstrap pre-built class "table-responsive" works great. it gives the table/div scroll bars sideways when in mobile view and there for maintaining the viewport.

BUT i also noticed that content steps outside the containing div and onto the main background div.

I have suplied an image below, (sorry the scroll bar horizontally i cut off) but you can see the white container content has stepped outside and onto the darker grey/blue color.

[image]

Here is an example of the table (bootstrap classes)

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">System Vitals</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <table id="vitals" class="table table-hover table-responsive">
                <tr>
                    <th>Hostname</th>
                    <td><span data-bind="Hostname"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Listening IP</th>
                    <td><span data-bind="IPAddr"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Kernel Version</th>
                    <td><span data-bind="Kernel"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Distro Name</th>
                    <td><span data-bind="Distro"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Uptime</th>
                    <td><span data-bind="Uptime"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Last boot</th>
                    <td><span data-bind="LastBoot"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Current Users</th>
                    <td><span data-bind="Users"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Load Averages</th>
                    <td><span data-bind="LoadAvg"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="tr_SysLang">
                    <th>System Language</th>
                    <td><span data-bind="SysLang"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="tr_CodePage">
                    <th>Code Page</th>
                    <td><span data-bind="CodePage"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="tr_Processes">
                    <th>Processes</th>
                    <td><span data-bind="Processes"></span></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Anyone know how to fix this if it is a bug?

Comment: I've put the table you supplied into JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/shfcmkhv/) but it seems the one you've given us is completely different from the one in your image.

Comment: Sorry. no data in table because i was pulling dynamically from a database and that was raw code.

Take a look at your jsfiddle now. If you reduce your browser down to a small size like a mobile, and use the scroll bars horizontally you will see the table column "Listening IP" that has random jibberish in it steps outside the container of the table./

Comment: Just put a `display: block;` on your `#vitals` element. https://jsfiddle.net/shfcmkhv/2/

Comment: Wow..... that was easy. Thanks so much Michael! If you posted it as an answer i would accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Michael the answer to this question was:
Just put a display: block; on your #vitals element. jsfiddle.net/shfcmkhv/2 – Michael